# Adjusting output of tail -f on website log

Tags: networking, monitoring, scripting

I am real-time monitoring my website logs with `tail -f`, but I am having trouble getting just the following to show in the results in this order:

```
Host Name - IP Address - Page - Date & Time
```

This is what i am trying to accomplish

http://qph.cf.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-fde4d84bf459d14aff0ef930e4f8c7fe

Thanks to Stephan & user157574 i am very close to to my goal!!

Comment: this is very vage.. are you trying to parse and display apache access_logs ? please be more specific

Comment: Post a sample of the original log.

Comment: yes i am using the access_log from apache, here is a screen shot

http://qph.cf.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-fde4d84bf459d14aff0ef930e4f8c7fe

Also would as shown like to see the load show by <=======>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an nginx log example that should take you about 80% of the way there:

```
# tail -f /var/log/nginx/hostname.log | awk '{ print "hostname" $1 $7 $4 }'
```

Effectively, you're piping the tail through awk, and swapping a few fields around and adding the name.  I'm not sure what you meant by Counter, but anything in a log field can be reordered, added, or removed.  The above command assumes IP is the first field, Page is the seventh field, and timestamp is the fourth; YMMV.

UPDATE:  If you wanted to save this data as a new log, you could do something like:

```
# tail -f /var/log/nginx/hostname.log | awk '{ print "hostname" $1 $7 $4 }' > /path/to/new/log.log
```

And to follow *that* log,

```
# tail -f /path/to/new/log.log
```

Every time new data is added to the log, tail -f (-f for follow) will spit the contents of the log out to your screen.

### EDIT:

Keep in mind that "hostname" is something you would type, i.e. the host name of the log you're reading.  How you come up with that variable is entirely up to you (you could set it based on the log file name, i.e. '{ print "somefancyserver.com" $1 $7 $4 }'

For even more control over your real time logging system, you might want to look into

graylog2.org

logstash.net

or (if you have deep pockets)

splunk.com

Comment: thanks, this helps with my issue of getting multiple lines to show using awk

when i run it as follows i get the following errors

cat cannot open log

Comment: My bad, here's the updated version: # tail -f /var/log/nginx/hostname.log | awk '{ print "hostname" $1 $7 $4 }'

Comment: cat cannot open log

and hostname just shows as hostname

thank you very much for the help, this is getting me where i am trying to go, here is a screen shot of a script just like what i am trying to do

http://qph.cf.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-fde4d84bf459d14aff0ef930e4f8c7fe

Comment: the log i am using is /var/log/httpd/access_log

Comment: how do i put it into a shell script and get it to i guess whats called a loop for every 10 sec so its updating the results

Comment: using tail -f means that the output is constantly polled for new data, and spit out (in this case, in a pipe to awk, which shuffles the data in the fields around, and then spits out to standard out.)  In effect, the files are being output in (close to) real time.  I'll update my original answer for more info....

Comment: combining awk '{ x = $2 " " $4 " " $7 ; printf "%-15s %-20s %4d\n", $1, x, $7}' with the tail -f access_log got me closer, now to just put it in a script

Comment: do you like graylog2.org or 
logstash.net better if you were trying to create what is in my screen shot

Comment: You'd probably find logstash faster to stand up, and more effective at polling for new queries.  Splunk is the jet engine of the bunch, but incredibly expensive.